# getDay() in Javascript Error

Tags: javascript

Can anybody shed some light on getDay() in Javascript please.
Here datepicker is textbox where it gets value from Jquery DatePicker Control

```
var CallbackDateNumber;
// check for the value in Date of callback control
if(("#datepicker")!="")
{
    CallbackDateNumber = new Date($("#datepicker").val()).getDay();
}
else
{
    CallbackDateNumber=new Date().getDay();
}
```

For January Date its gives 0,1...6- From Sunday to Saturday.

But the same order is not preserved in Month Febraury.

Any reason why this happening?

Comment: You do realize you are calling two different methods, `getDay` and `getDate`, right?

Comment: for 05/02/2012 I get 3, 06/02/2012 I get 6.for 11/02/2012 I get 5.

Comment: @Brian: that was typo in my original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates need to be in `MM/DD/YYYY` format. It's parsing 05/02/2012 as May 2, 2012 and 06/02/2012 as June 2, 2012.

Comment: Thank you. I was passing date as dd/mm/yy format. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

You're using [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) (= day in the month) instead of [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) (= day of the week) at the `else` block. Replace `getDate` with `getDay`:

```
CallbackDateNumber = new Date().getDay();
```

Comment: sorry: there was a typo in my question.. I have updated it.. sorry. Can you have a look now please?

Comment: @StewieFG Can you show the real code, if the following doesn't fix your issue: Replace `if(("#datepicker")!="")` with `if($("#datepicker").val()!="")`